# How to save the data setting and not revert back when refresh the app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to use toggle buttons for my **ionic** app settings.

I used `window.localStorage` to save the data.

My problem is the setting, it gets revert back when I refresh or restart the app and I kinda lost here.

I don't know how to load the saved data. Here is my code :

html:

```
  <div class="list">

    <div class="item item-divider"> 
      Settings
    </div>

  </div>

  <ion-toggle ng-model="favorite.checked"
                ng-change="favoriteChange()">
      favorite
  </ion-toggle>
```

js:

```
$scope.favoriteChange = function() {
window.localStorage['favorites'] = angular.toJson($scope.favorite.checked);
}
$scope.favorite = { checked:true};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never retrieving the value you stored.

`localStorage`: [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
$scope.favorite = {};

// Loads on page load/controller load
$scope.favorite["checked"] = localStorage.getItem("favorites");

// If never set
if($scope.favorite.checked == null) {
    $scope.favorite.checked = true;
}

// Save
$scope.favoriteChange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", $scope.favorite.checked);
}
```

You could also use [ngStorage](https://medium.com/@petehouston/awesome-local-storage-for-ionic-with-ngstorage-c11c0284d658#.f6s5ql9wf), it has better functionality for larger objects saving.